# Selenium set speed execution test

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

We use Selenium IDE to record the test. In the recorder we can change the speed execution and our tests pass. We should set the speed to SLOW.

I use ANT for launch the HTML Suite test.

The problem is that we have to **set the execution speed of the test**.

*Which is the right parameter for setting this property? Exist something for setting it?*

```
<target name="run-selenium-tests">
    <echo message="Using browser = ${browser} "/>
    <taskdef resource="selenium-ant.properties" classpathref="class.path">
    </taskdef>
    <java jar="${acceptance.test.lib.dir}/selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc3.jar" fork="true">
        <arg line="-htmlSuite ${browser}"/>
        <arg line="http://myserver:8080/"/>
        <arg line="../sampletest/selenium/my_test.html"/>
        <arg line="../sampletest/selenium/report/results.html"/>
        <arg line="-timeout 1000"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

Can anyone help us?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use following selenium command for slowing the speed of Execution

```
    setSpeed(value in milliseconds)
```

This command will wait  for the specified value after each exection of command.